# Regular epimorphisms in the category of topological rings

Tags: category-theory, epimorphisms, topological-rings

I believe regular epimorphisms in the category of topological groups are precisely the surjective open maps. Is this also true for the category of topological rings? If not, is there some other characterization of the regular epimorphisms in TopRing? A reference would be very much appreciated.

This question is now cross-posted at MathOverflow:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416708/regular-epimorphisms-in-the-category-of-topological-rings

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered on MathOverflow.